# lme versus aov repeated measures variance specification

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I am performing a repeated measures ANOVA in R, where the experimental design is composed of a between-subjects factor (`Prodotto`, three levels), the within-subjects factor is time (`Tempo`, four levels&mdahs;an ordered factor) and each `Product * Time` is repeated on eleven patients (`idPaziente`).

The `aov()` syntax would be:

```
myAov<-aov(valore ~ Tempo*Prodotto + Error(idPaziente/Tempo),data=mydata)
```

whilst the `lme()` (from the `nlme` package) syntax would be

```
myModel <- lme(valore ~  Tempo*Prodotto,data=mydata, random= ~ 1 | idPaziente/Tempo)
```

In Finch (2014) [*Multilevel Modeling with R*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466515856),  I find a specification of a longitudinal model that would be written as:

```
myModel <- lme(valore ~  Tempo*Prodotto,data=mydata, random= ~ 1 | idPaziente)
```

I guess the equivalent `aov` version would have `Error(idPaziente)` instead of `Error(idPaziente/Tempo)`.

I would like to ask:

1. What is the correct specification for my repeated measures model, both for `aov()` and `lme()`?
2. Why are `(1 | idPaziente/Tempo)` and `Error(idPaziente/Tempo)` more appropriate than `(1 | idPaziente)` and `Error(idPaziente)`?
3. How can I perform post hoc analysis taking on the Prodotto term?

Comment: This is borderline, but IMO it may have just enough statistical content to be considered on topic here.

Comment: Hi Giorgio - Just out of curiosity, did my answer worked for the problem you were experiencing? Or can I update it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your nesting structure (example dataset):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  idPaziente = rep(c(1:12), each = 11), 
  Tempo = rep(c(1:4),33),
  Prodotto = rep(letters[1:3], 11, each = 4),
  valore = rnorm(132, 6, 1)  
)
```

Using `random = ~ 1 | idPaziente/Tempo`:

```
fit <- lme(valore ~  Tempo * Prodotto, data = df, random = ~ 1 | idPaziente/Tempo)
```

To get the ANOVA table you could do:

```
library(car)
Anova(fit)
```

If your `idPaziente` and `Tempo` is explicitly nested,

```
df$newID <- with(df, paste(idPaziente, Tempo, sep = "-"))
```

you only need to specify `random = ~ 1 | newID`

```
fit2 <- lme(valore ~  Tempo * Prodotto, data = df, random = ~ 1 | newID)

Anova(fit2)
```

then:

`summary(fit)` and `summary(fit2)` will give you the same results. Also have a look at the `Number of Groups:` statement. This is a good check to see whether your nesting worked out correctly and reflects your data structure.

If `Prodotto` is significant, you could follow up with:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(fit, pairwise ~ Prodotto)
lsmeans(fit2, pairwise ~ Prodotto)
```

And the same should hold for the `aov()` function, too.